# Bootstrap datepicker calendar not displaying for the below code

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am unable to display the calendar to book an appointment in the below code. Can anyone help me in getting the right solution. Not sure if script for datepicker should be included within php or outside.

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>abc</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/justdental_style.css">
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <?php
  include_once("connection.php");

  $sql = "SELECT FIRST_NAME,QUALIFICATION,Specialization,LAST_NAME,   
  Adress1, Consultation_Fee, Experience, Adress2 from t_doctorprofile";
  $results = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die('Error in connection');

  echo '<h3 style="color:purple"><strong>Available Dentists</strong></h3>';

  while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
      echo '<div class="fetch">';

      echo "<p>".$result['FIRST_NAME']." ".$result['LAST_NAME']."</p>";

      echo "<p>".$result['QUALIFICATION']."</p>";
      echo "<p>".$result['Specialization']."</p>";
      echo "<p>".$result['Adress1']." ".$result['Adress2']."</p>";
      echo "<p>"."<b>Consultation Fee-</b>"." ".$result['Consultation_Fee']."</p>";
      echo "<p>"."<b>Experience-</b>"." ".$result['Experience']."years"."</p>";

      echo "<div class='container'>";
      echo "<div class='row'>";
      echo "<div class='col-sm-2' style='margin-left:130px;margin-top:120px;'>";
      echo   "<div class='form-group'>";
      echo  "<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>";
      echo   "<input type='text' class='form-control' />";
      echo "<span class='input-group-addon'>";
      echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'>";
      echo "</span>";

      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";

      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';

  } 
  ?>     

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: This is not the full code. I see the closing tag for PHP, but I don't see the opening one. Please post it all.

Comment: `echo '<div class="fetch">';
     //echo $result['FIRST_NAME']." ".$result['QUALIFICATION']."      
     ".$result['Specialization'];
     //echo "<td><img src='uploads/$row[1].png' height='100px'   
     width='300px'></td>";` there's a problem here. You commented out some of those lines, but the ones below some of them, were not commented out.

Comment: Plus, where is the `datetimepicker1` id? You don't have code to support the question.

Comment: ask the guy below who gave you an answer. I will have to pass on this question, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all datetimepicker dependencies (jQuery, moment.js, bootstrap.js) as stated in the [documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/). You should add the import code in the `head` or at the end of the html (before initializing the datepicker). An example of import is the following (obviously you need to configure the right path):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

The html for your datetimepicker is inside a `while` loop, so you need to use a `class` instead of an `id`. Your html should be like this:

```
echo  "<div class='input-group date' class='datetimepicker5'>"
```

and your init code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datetimepicker5').datetimepicker();
});
```

Please note that you are missing `body` tag and the `<span class='input-group-addon'>` is never closed.

Answer (score 0):

I  have noticed that you added `datetimepicker5` id into a div, it should be applied to a `input type text`

Comment: I have those links buddy.

Comment: you mean this way-- echo   "<input type='text' class='form-control' class='datetimepicker5'/>";

Comment: not class, id! Your jquery is picking from `#` which is the selector for id, if you want class you must use a dot `.`